# NSTime create a timeInterval

Tags: objective-c, time, nstimer, nstimeinterval

I have the following code in my application in the method `updateLabel2`:

```
timeLeft = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastDate"]];

[[self timer] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time Remaining: %f", timeLeft]]; //Set the label text
```

Note that timer is a label.

and earlier, the following code is executed:

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"lastDate"];


self.repeatTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                               target:self
                                             selector:@selector(updateLabel2) 
                                             userInfo:nil
                                              repeats:YES];
```

My problem is that timeLeft is being set to random integers which are definetly not what the timeIntervals should be, and are not within one second of each other either.

Comment: Instead of/in addition to setting the text of a label, can you please `NSLog(@"Time Remaining: %f", timeLeft)` and post an excerpt of the console log here? It's getting difficult to diagnose your problem without knowing what exactly you are doing and seeing…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format-string is wrong:
Because `NSTimeInterval` is a floating point type, you need to either

- use the appropriate placeholder `%f` instead of `%d` or
- cast `timeLeft` to an int while calling `-[NSString stringWithFormat:]`.

Which — I think — is, what Justin referred to.

#### Aside

Considering what you're doing there:
Shouldn't that be "Time *elapsed*"?

Comment: I did that and I'm still having the problems (I was originally crashing because of this error but fixed it.  I thought I had edited that here)